# Return to the original activity after starting a new activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have an Activity A and I call Activity B. The problem is if I navigate away from B and come back to B again, after this once activity B is finished, I am redirected to the Android Home screen rather then the original activity A. I need to find a way to get back to A. Here is the complete flow:

A -> B -> (Navigate from B to some activity or home screen) -> (come back to B) -> (B finished after calling finish()) -> (Android Home screen is shown)

**Expected result:**

A -> B -> (Navigate from B to some activity or home screen) -> (come back to B) -> (B finished after calling finish()) -> **(A should be shown)**

I understand this is due to the way in which Activities are stacked and since I navigate from B the Android Home screen becomes the top of the stack and that is why A is not shown. However is there a way in which I can manipulate the top of stack to come back to A. I tried Intent flags and its combination but it did not work for me. I may have missed something if you can help or is there any other way to do it?

Comment: You need to show exactly how you are invoking the activity B.

Comment: Using startActivityForResult. I pass in an intent with "B" activity class name and currently I use the flag "FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP" I even tried without it but not the expected result

Comment: All the ways described at official doc, please, read it first. http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html
Ah, I thought you're speaking generally. So sorry. But also useful I think.

Comment: you should set Activity A as parent activity of Activity B

Comment: I have read this but still could not find a way to do what I intended. Is there another way?

Comment: The standard Android behaviour should do exactly what you want. You must be doing something funky, Please post your manifest.

Comment: I think the standard behavior is correct. As A is no longer the activity on top of stack that is why the home screen is shown. I know this is the problem and it is actually expected. I would like to know if there is a way I can manipulate this standard behavior where I can manipulate the activity stack to allow **A** to run after **B** is finished

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `finish()` is called for `Activity A`, that's why it's not displayed when you want it. First step is to check if you're accidentally calling `finish()` yourself.

Also keep in mind that it's possible that the system has killed (finished) `Activity A`. This can happen if there's big need for memory ... for example if your `Activity B` is super heavy (e.g. doing lots of Bitmap transformations) it could be just that.

Lastly, if possible you can specify parentActivity of `B` to be `A`, by adding this in your manifest `android:parentActivityName="....activity.A"`. This way Android will open A when you back from B.

Comment: Finish is not called on Activity A. How do I set a parent and will it help me to return back to the activity A even though it may not be on top of stack?

Comment: Yes, it should help you. See more details about parentActivity here: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html#SpecifyParent. Setting it is just by adding the line I have you in for Activity B in the manifest file.

Comment: If its declaring in the manifest of B, I can't do that, if it is in the intent that I pass from A then yes. The reason being that activity B can be called by many activities apart from A and the expected behavior is that I should return to those activities once B finishes. So I cannot declare a single parent for B. Basically when I gave the example, I should have been more clear but A is not the alone parent for B

Comment: Ok, in that case the parentActivity thing won't work for you :( Will post if I have any new ideas how to solve your problem!